# How do I find the base?

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

Let $W\subset(\mathbb{R}^3)^*$ be a subspace formed by the functionals $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $Kerf =[(-4,-4,0),(0,2,2)]$.
Find a basis of $W$

The idea I had was: Consider a basis $B=\left\lbrace (-4,-40),(0,2,2)\right\rbrace$ of the $Kerf$ then find a dual basis to $B$ using the Kronecker delta function but the base elements. 
I found do not meet the kernel hypothesis. 
Any idea or suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: $Nucf$ mean what?

Comment: @PaulSinclair Kernel f* sorry

Comment: Every element of ${\Bbb R^3}^*$ corresponds to some vector in $\Bbb R^3$ using the inner product: There is some $a \in \Bbb R^3$ such that for all $v \in \Bbb R^3, f(v) = a \cdot v$. That those two vectors $b_1, b_2$ are in the kernel of $f$ means that $a\cdot b_1 = a\cdot b_2 = 0$. That is, $a$ is orthogonal to both. Find the space of all $a$ that are orthgonal to both vectors. Then convert that space to the corresponding space of functionals, per that inner product relationship.